# block end if without if

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If TextBox2.Text = "qwerty1234" Then
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
        Dim x As Integer
        For x = 5 To 7
            ActivePresentation.Slides(x).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTriStateToggle
        Next x
    End
    Else
        If MsgBox("Did you forget your password? Try again, ensuring you use the correct case.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Sorry!") = vbOK Then
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Now when the code is indented, can you see it?

Comment: It would be nice if you put a little effort into your question.

Answer (score 1):

As GS says you need a second End If (and delete the end)  Even so though your code makes no sense what do you want to happen after the message?

Maybe you mean:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

 If TextBox2.Text = "qwerty1234" Then
 ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
 Dim x As Integer
 For x = 5 To 7
 ActivePresentation.Slides(x).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTriStateToggle
 Next x
 Else
 MsgBox "Did you forget your password? Try again, ensuring you use the correct case.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Sorry!"
 TextBox2.Text = ""
 End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another `End If`. You have one, but you have two `If` statements.

Comment: What about the `End`?

Comment: @DougGlancy It's [just a command](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/HV080354392.aspx).

Comment: @GSerg, a confusing and unneeded one :), assuming I understand the code's intent.